# Livewire instance in variable sets itself null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

in my laravel livewire component, i have this code.

```
private $wireAlertService;

public function mount() {
    $this->supervisors = User::getSupervisors();

    $this->wireAlertService = new LivewireAlertService();

    // dd($this->wireAlertService);
}
```

the commented out `dd()` dumps the instance of `LivewireAlertService` as wanted.

however, in other method, that fire's on button's `wire:click`, the variable `$wireAlertService` is null.

```
public function approveMany($attrs) {

    // code

    dd($this->wireAlertService, (new LivewireAlertService()));
    // $this->wireAlertService->success($this);
    // (new LivewireAlertService())->success($this);
}
```

in method `approveMany()` `dd()` dumps this

```
null
App\Services\LivewireAlertService {#2760}
```

therefore `$this->wireAlertService->success($this);` does not work (the desired one)
while `(new LivewireAlertService())->success($this);` works, but i don't like it as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described within the [introduction](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#introduction) of Livewire, `protected` and `private` properties do not persist. Therefore, after your mount is completed, the property is reset.

If you wish to have it be persistent, you need to define it immediately, but this is not possible using a class instantiation, or make the property `public`.

Dependent on what the service is, you could [inject](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters) it into each method, much like you would with the [`Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#method-injection).